# PHP / MySQL: Calculate two unrelated tables and present in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

New to PHP so apologies :-)

I have two tables in MySQL but they have no columns in common for me to join.

I want to use PHP to create a html table that draws the data from both MySQL tables and uses a field in the second table to multiply a value in the first.  I have connected the database OK and can display the first table in a html table OK but cannot get the second table values imported to be used in currency calculations.

To simplify ->

```
Table 1
--------
part_name: Text
Part_value: decimal

Table 2 (only 5 rows / currencies will be used)
--------
currency_name: Text
exch_rate: decimal
```

The html table should show as follows:

> `part_name  /  part_value  /  part_value * exch_rate (from table 2, row 1) /  part_value * exch_rate (from table 2, row 2) /  part_value * exch_rate (from table 2, row 3) etc...`

I currently have the html showing as follows (note the missing values in the Price xxx columns:

```
Part Name     Part Value     Price USD   Price CNY   (Header Row)
--------------------------------------------------
part_name  /  part_value  /
```

I am using a SELECT statement to bring in the values of Table 1 and using IF to iterate the rows.
What should I do to get the exch_rate values in to calculate the values for each of the 'Price xxx' columns.

Sorry if this seems a bit vague.  I am trying to pick this up so if you can point me in the right direction I will attempt to code it myself.  Best way to learn :-)

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. just doa  regular join, do a normal column-based retrieval, then use client-side code to convert the normal result set into a multi-column output.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I do a regular join though as there are no related fields in both tables?

Comment: you kind of need a cross-join anyways, since you WANT to multiple by all currencies anyways. so a `join currencies on 1` is good enough.

Comment: That looks interesting! Watch this space. Thanks

Comment: I have taken a look at this but it results in every possible iteration against all currencies with those results showing in the Price USD column rather than spread across all Price xxx columns.  It's a start, cheers.

Comment: no, you'd do `select ..., part_value, part_value*exchange_rate AS localized_value, currency_name`. that gives you ONE column with "local" prices, and another column that says which currency that local price is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can either perform a cross join:

```
select
  p.*,
  c.*,
  p.part_value * c.exch_rate as localValue
from
  Parts p
  cross join Currency c
```

But then you will still have to pull apart that information to display it in a table.

Or you can simply query the relevant parts, get the exchange rates in a separate query, and perform the multiplication in PHP, roughly something like this:

```
<?php
$parts = <<query all parts>>
$currencies = <<query all currencies>>

// Column headers
?><tr><th>name</th><?

foreach($currencies as $currency) {
  ?><th><?=$currency->currency_name?></th><?
}
?></tr><?

// Part data
foreach ($parts as $part) {
  // Start row and show part name
  ?><tr><td><?=$part->part_name?></td><?

  // Each of the prices
  foreach($currencies as $currency) {
    ?><td><?=$part->part_value * $currency->exchange_rate?>;
  }
  ?></tr><?
}
```

As you can see, the code is quite simple, only needing a nested foreach loop, to iterator over the parts, and then over each of the currencies per part. This is probably much easier and less 'dirty' than iterating over the result of the cross join and determining when to start a new row.

You will need an extra request to the database, but on the other hand, you will return much less data. After all, a cross join of P parts with C currencies, will result i P*C rows, while two queries results in P + C rows.

Comment: This looks interesting too.  I will give it a go. Thanks!